# How to Interpret Reflective Measurement Model?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, psychometrics, psychology, scale-construction

Given $F$ is a latent construct (cause), and $Y_1$, $Y_2$, and $Y_3$ are the manifest (indicator) variables (effects) which are measured. Then, there are two groups of people (A and B). According to the measurement result, people in Group A averagely have higher scores in all effects: Y1, Y2, and Y3. Namely:

- Group A's average score of Y1 is higher than Group B's average score of Y1
- Group A's average score of Y2 is higher than Group B's average score of Y2
- Group A's average score of Y3 is higher than Group B's average score of Y3.

Then, how can I conclude or interpret the result:

1. All people in Group A have higher X than do all people in Group B.
2. The people in Group A averagely have higher X than do the people in Group B.
3. The people in Group A may averagely have higher X than may the people in Group B.
4. The people in Group A are more likely to have higher X than are the people in Group B.

Which interpretation(s) are correct or none of the above?
I guess (3) and (4) are correct, but not sure. (2) also looks not bad.

Could anyone please teach me how to interpret the result of reflective models?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

In your sample, only 2) is a valid interpretation. In your population, only 3) is a valid interpretation. The interpretation is no different than that of a t-test with observed variables. But this should be based on a measurement model and an appropriate statistical technique; making inferences just based on the distributions of the indicators is not enough. For example, do the items measure the construct in the same way in groups A and B? If not, you can't make inferences just by looking at the items. You need a latent variable model and to test measurement invariance before you can make any conclusion. It's not clear that you have done this.